# Atlas Integration with kerberized Hbase and solr

Tags: solr, hbase, kerberos, apache-atlas, bigtop

I successfully configured Apache Atlas of version 2.3.0 with my HBase and Solr instances, and everything was functioning smoothly. Subsequently, I implemented Kerberos security for both HBase and Solr, ensuring that each service had its own principles and keytabs.

Now, I'm interested in integrating Apache Atlas with my Kerberos-secured HBase and Solr installations. However, I'm encountering an access issue(unauthorized access in solr) when trying to use the HBase principle while integrating, and conversely, I face access problems in HBase when utilizing the Solr (HTTP) principle.

Can anyone give the guidance on how to effectively integrate Atlas with my Kerberos-secured HBase and Solr instances.